# Pressing Back Button from the intent to return Fragment disappears the recyclerview list items in Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, loader, swiperefreshlayout

I have list items of custom object and I am using recyclerview to show them and using loaders for internet connection. My problem is when you click an item Google Chrome Custom Tabs intent is triggered (you are redirected to related website) but when you press back button from the website to return the fragment, the recylerview items disappears (interestingly it disappears a few seconds later). I want to return back to the previous screen without refreshing. There is no error. It happened after I added the SwipeRefreshlayout. 
I am sharing the related code parts:

```
public class FragmentTopNews extends Fragment
    implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<NewsItem>>, NewsAdapter.OnItemClickListener{

...
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

....

    // SwipeRefreshlayout for refreshing the data
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.srl_refresher);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimary, R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.canChildScrollUp();
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            mNewsAdapter.clearData();
            mNewsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            // Restart the loader
            LoaderManager.getInstance(FragmentTopNews.this).restartLoader
                    (NEWS_LOADER_ID, null, FragmentTopNews.this);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(String newsUrl) {

    CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
    CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
    customTabsIntent.launchUrl(getActivity(), Uri.parse(newsUrl));
}

@NonNull
@Override
public android.support.v4.content.Loader<List<NewsItem>> onCreateLoader(int i, @Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    return new NewsLoaderTopNews(getContext(), NEWS_URLS);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull android.support.v4.content.Loader<List<NewsItem>> loader, List<NewsItem> newsItems) {

    // Hide loading indicator because the data has been loaded
    mLoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    // Hide refreshing indicator
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    if (newsItems != null && !newsItems.isEmpty()) {
        // Clear the adapter of previous data
        mNewsAdapter.clearData();
        // pass in the news data to the adapter
        mNewsAdapter.setNewsData(newsItems);

        mNewsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    } else { // tell the user that the news can't be loaded
        mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mErrorView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mErrorView.setText(R.string.no_data);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull android.support.v4.content.Loader<List<NewsItem>> loader) {

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onLoaderReset is called");

    // Clear the adapter of previous data
    mNewsAdapter.clearData();

    }
}
```

And this is the onstartLoading override method:

```
    //this is required to trigger the loader to start doing background work
@Override
protected void onStartLoading() {

        forceLoad();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add more description, onCreate, onCreateView, onViewCreated, onPause, onResume, what happened in this methods?

Comment: the first part is onCreateView. I didn't add onViewCreated, onPause, onResume, should I add codes to these methods to keep the list?

Comment: Why did you call mNewsAdapter.clearData(); in 3 places?!

Comment: there is no specific reason for that, just my logic and what i learned. If i shouldn't add any of them i can delete. But for example if i delete it from onloadfinish, then when i click back button  the list items get doubled.

Comment: i think it is better to put your complete code, may be?

Comment: ok I put the complete code

Comment: I think it is enough to call it in onLoaderReset. Also it can is cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the issue.

I noticed that when i click back button, the loader is started again (which I don't want) and in my AsynctaskLoader's OnStart method I have "forceload()" command which is executed everytime. So I changed it to this:

```
    @Override
protected void onStartLoading() {
    // Added this check to not load data when back button is triggered.
    if (news == null || news.isEmpty()) {
        forceLoad();
    }
}
```